# Error in Postgres to_regclass Treats Table Name as Column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I had the following query in Python (SQLAlchemy) code.

```
r = list(conn.execute(f"SELECT 'OK' FROM {table} LIMIT 1"))[0][0]
```

A case occurred where the table was truncated (it exists, but has no data in it). This line would error in this (edge) case. Hence, I am trying to change it to

```
        r = list(
            conn.execute(
                f"SELECT case when(SELECT to_regclass({table}) is not NULL) "
                f"then 'OK' else 'FAIL' end;"
            )
        )[0][0]
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
 File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "<table>" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT case when(SELECT to_regclass(<table>) is no...
```

Essentially, I am trying to make sure that the query still works and returns fail when the table is empty. How can I do that and/or why am I getting the error?

Comment: 1) This *A case occurred where the table was dropped (it exists, but has no data in it).*  is wrong. If the table is `DROP`ed it does not exist. To get what describe it would need to be truncated or a complete table delete done. 2) Do not use `f` strings to build a query, use parameters. 3) The error is probably occurring because of 2) . Pass the table name as a parameter to the function, then it will be properly typed and escaped.  Right now I'm guessing the query is hitting the database as `...SELECT to_regclass(table)...` instead of what it should be `...SELECT to_regclass('table')...`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver

1. Yes, it was truncated. I misspoke.
2. Parameters in which sense?

Also, where I wrote `<table>`, I am getting the actual table name substituted. So, it seems that it unpacks it alright, just somehow thinks it is a column?

Comment: `conn.execute("SELECT case when(SELECT to_regclass(:table) is not NULL) then 'OK' else 'FAIL' end", table='table_name')`. This is for the  older version of SQLAlchemy < 2.0. If you are using 2.0 you  will need to search on SQLAlchemy 2.0 execute parameters for examples.

Comment: Which version of Postgres?  `to_regclass` was added in 9.4.  And, by the way, `to_regclass` tells you whether the table exists or not, not whether it is empty or not.  Wouldn't a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {table}` be more useful?

Comment: @TimRoberts, it never got to querying the table as it was seeing `<table>` not as the string it should be but as an unquoted identifier.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver -- I totally missed that subtlety.  Of course, you are correct.  `to_regclass` needs a string as a parameter, not a name.

Comment: @TimRoberts Postgres version is 11. Are you saying it is better to use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {table}` in my case?

Comment: The problem is no the query, it is your parameter handling. Look at the error message, in particular `...column "<table>" does not exist ...`. You are not passing in what you think  you think you are and part of the issue is using string interpolation not proper parameters.

Comment: You can repair what you have by using `to_regclass("{table}")` -- notice the quotes -- but that will only tell you whether the table exists or not.  What you SAID is that the table always exists, and you want to know if it is empty or not.  `COUNT` is the way to do that.